# Force feedkeys to paste characters immediately

Tags: vim

I am writing a plugin to enhance lexics (e.g. automatically close brackets/quotes, filetype specific rules, etc) and some things have unexpected behavior for me. The plugin rule looks like this one:

```
{"key": "'", "pattern": '...', "keys": "'\<Left>"}
```

Since I am listening to **InsertCharPre** event to detect what key has been pressed, there is some restrictions in editing buffer directly using `setline`, for instance (:help textlock). So I have to change `v:char` variable or call `feedkeys` instead of. The problem with `v:char` is it cannot operate with special keys (it just inserts an escaped sequence) like "\", "\" and others (however, "\" seems to be handled correctly) which are frequently used in the plugin. So my only option is feedkeys, but if there is a `key` in the `keys` (see above), vim starts a recursion. I know about `<C-v>` insert mode mapping but there can be a lot of such keys that will make adding new rules more complex. If there is no other option, I think, the best decision would be use `set paste` option but as subject indicates I have some troubles with it.

```
...
set paste

call feedkeys("'\<Left>")

set nopaste
...
```

It seems that the whole body of the function is executed firstly and then the characters are inserted to the buffer at the moment when `paste` is already `nopaste`. Further reading of `feedkeys` help was not successful (I tried different modes). You can try this simple code to see what I am talking about:

```
function! s:Foo()
    startinsert

    call feedkeys("ff")

    stopinsert
endfunction

nnoremap <silent><CR> :call <SID>Foo()<CR>
```

Buffer should not contain any text after pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> but if you comment `stopinsert` command, everything goes as expected.

Ps: I know about **lexima** plugin but do not want to use it. I tried to solve the problem exploring the source code of **lexima** but there is `inoremap <expr>` which I also do not want to use :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`feedkeys()` is about inserting keys into the *typeahead buffer*. Keys from this buffer are only consumed *after* the current command / function has ended (or if you explicitly read keys, e.g. via `getchar()`). That explains you struggles to have the keys processed immediately; the function isn't meant for that :-) To submit keys immediately, you'd use `:normal`. Yes, that doesn't work with textlock.

Based on your problem, I think using `feedkeys()` with the `n` mode (i.e. *do not remap keys*) should work. The keys won't be affected by user mappings, so you know exact which (built-in) keys need to be escaped. If you really needed to brace your keys with e.g. changing `'paste'`, you'd have to put the toggle commands inside `feedkeys()` as well:

```
:call feedkeys(":set paste\<CR>\<Left>:set nopaste\<CR>")
```

Comment: Yes, this works. But since plugin works in insert mode there should be `\<C-o>:set paste\<CR>` or `\<C-r>=SomeFunction()\<CR>`. As for me, the last one is better because it does not leave insert mode which causes cursor to move one character left. Also there is no need to move `:set paste` into `feedkeys` function, so the final code for me is:
    `set paste`
    `let output = printf("%s\<C-r>=lexics#setNoPaste()\<CR>", rule.keys)`
    `call feedkeys(output, "n")`

Comment: The code already works but if there are some tricks with `v:char` variable it would be better. Do you know some? I mentioned it before but the parser ruined this. `v:char` can contain `\<CR>` key (I mean the newline is inserted in the right way) but others cannot.